# JQuery select duplication and removal of options

Tags: jquery, forms, dom

I am using the JQuery plugin twosidedmultiselect http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/cmsfiles/assets/File/twosidedmultiselect.html and then once options are placed in the dynamically created select they are also cloned to a third select. However, if options already cloned are then removed from the dynamic select they need to be removed from the third select box as well, in essence the contents of the dynamic select need to be exactly the same as the third select.

Anyone come across this before or know of a fix?

Or how to remove all previously cloned options before initiating .clone with a .focus function?

Comment: OK i have solved this one with return !$('#primaryGroup').html($("#myselect").html()).prepend('<option>Everybody</option>');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this one off

return !$('#thirdselect').html($("#dynamicselect").html()).prepend('Applies to All');